# Pthread doesn't work when some specific number of threads are used

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I met a weird phenomenon: my C program doesn't work at some specific number of threads, e.g. 8.

When I debug with "fprintf", I found the problem occurs in the creation of pthreads:

```
298 /* work for each thread */
299 void* work(void *t)
300 {
301   long tid;
302   tid = (long)t;
303   fprintf(stderr, "In thread %lu\n", tid);
304
...
368   pthread_exit((void*)t);
369 }

513 /* main function */
514 int my_main(struct Params params)
515 {
...
      pthread_t* threads;
      threads = malloc(threads_num * sizeof(pthread_t));
574   long t;
575   int rc;
576   for (t=0; t<threads_num; t++)
577   {
578     fprintf(stderr, "create %lu\n", t);
579     rc = pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, work, (void*)t);
580     if(rc)
581     {
582       printf("ERROR: return code from pthread_creat() is %d\n", rc);
583       exit(-1);
584     }
585   }
...
599   for(t=0; t<threads_num; t++)
600     pthread_join(threads[t], NULL);
...
615   return 0;
616 }
```

The results look like:

```
create 0
create 1
create 2
create 3
create 4
create 5
In thread 0
In thread 3
In thread 4
create 6
In thread 1
In thread 2
In thread 5
create 7
In thread 6
Segmentation fault
```

What potential problems could happen for thread 7? Any thoughts?

Other info may be useful is: The codes run well on my MacBook Pro with GCC as the compiler.
The problems here are the cases I compile them on some Linux servers (openSUSE) with GCC.

Comment: Is that the actual code? Did you probably originally write: `fprintf(stderr, "p%d\n", (int)t);`?

Comment: @Shahbaz That is the actual one, not the one you wrote.

Comment: I don't think there is anything going on other than you are spinning out threads ("p2") faster than they get scheduled and run ("p3")

Comment: The simple explanation is that you don't wait for these threads to complete and that real main() function exits before they get a chance to run.

Comment: Normally, you don't get troubles with pthreads creating 8 threads. So please show us a minimal but complete program that exposes the behavior. An insufficient size of `threads` array or premature exit from `main` can be a cause of error, but it's hard to say looking at several pieces.

Comment: @Hans Passant, yup that's it.  OP - either `pthread_join` your threads or `pthread_exit` your main.

Comment: Shahbaz, Duck,  Hans Passant, Inspired, I just updated my codes to make it more clear.

Comment: @JackWM, next time, please post the correct code. The question is quite changed now!

Comment: @Shahbaz You are right. Sorry for the change.

Comment: There is still a lot that could be responsible for the segfault in the elided code represented by "..." areas.  It would be helpful to post a complete program that still has the problem.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the above code. It actually compiles and runs fine with different values of threads_num. The segmentation fault is originating from somewhere else in the code. My suggestion is to run this under the debugger and inspect the stack trace.

Comment: @selbie I forgot to mention a thing: the codes run well on my MacBook Pro with gcc as the compiler. The problem I posted here is for some servers running openSUSE.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for all the answers and comments!

I found the source for this strange segmentation fault.

In some other parts of the codes, I loaded floating number to some arrays.
However I mistakenly used `malloc( sizeof(int) * length)`. Previously, I 
used `float` type, since `float` and `int` have the same size, this bug
didn't show up in my earlier versions of codes. But recently, I updated
the types from `float` to `double`, which leads to this strange behavior.

Sorry for putting the codes which are unrelated to the source of the bug.
I didn't expect this bug leads to the strange behaviors of pthread.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're overflowing the `threads` array. Since you haven't shown where it's declared, I can't be sure. Usually the first thing I do when trying to debug a segmentation fault is to fire up gdb. [RMS](http://www.unknownroad.com/rtfm/gdbtut/gdbsegfault.html) wrote a very good introduction to using a symbolic debugger to track down segfaults. GDB can handle fancy stuff like switching between threads, and will halt right at the instruction that caused the segfault without any manual setting of breakpoints.

Comment: Thanks, nmichaels. I added the declaration to the question. But it should not be the case. Since it works for large number of threads, like 90 threads.